# Formatting a hard drive for Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 4TB second drive on a Window 10 computer. I wanted to use 1TB for Ubuntu.
After spending 10 hours trying to partition that 1TB partition, I have had no luck at getting the Ubuntu USB drive to do the install.  The real stopper was asking for the boot code partition. That it not listed in the install script.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is too broad. Is the drive internal or external? And what's the "boot code partition"? Are you booting in BIOS or UEFI mode. I assume you're using UEFI since you have a big drive, so you need an [ESP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition), but if you're using an internal drive then there should already be an ESP for Windows, thus you don't need to create one

Comment: With a 4TiB drive you have gpt partitioning. Then to boot system you need either a bios_grub partition for BIOS booting or an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot. I normally make both partitions the first two partitions on every new drive and even flash drives. The I can install in BIOS or UEFI boot mode without having to totally redo drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu